# How to install a maven archetype that has Kotlin code which contains string interpolation?

Tags: maven, kotlin, jvm, velocity, maven-archetype

I'm trying to install a maven archetype that I created from a Kotlin project. Whenever I try to install the archetype, I get this error:

```
Archetype IT 'basic' failed: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Encountered "()}\"\n
```

the line of code that triggers the error is

```
return "redirect:${getRequestMapping()}"
```

Is there anything that I can do to solve this issue?
I use string interpolation a lot, and I don't want to replace them with concatenated strings

Answer (score 2):

The dollar sign '$' has meaning to Apache Velocity, which is the engine used by the archetypes. Velocity sees the '$', thinks it's supposed to do something with it, but the syntax is wrong (for Velocity) and it fails.

The fix here is to escape the dollar sign so Velocity ignores it as described in [documentation](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#escaping-invalid-vtl-references).

Something like this, which shows the dollar sign, but also others that might need to be escaped depending on use case:

```
## File will be filtered by Velocity - it is a Velocity template.
## Establish escape sequences for Velocity special chars.
#set( $symbol_pound = '#' )    
#set( $symbol_dollar = '$' )   
#set( $symbol_escape = '\' )

## Use the variable anywhere the interpolation is used
return "redirect:${symbol_dollar}{getRequestMapping()}"
```

The Velocity docs show this same technique using just 'D' as the variable name. I like the longer name for searchability and self-documentation.